# Can I add a GIT submodule to the existing project`s root, where files are not joint?

Tags: git, magento, themes, git-submodules

For example, I have Magento project:

```
app/design/frontend/base/
app/design/frontend/default/
errors/default/
errors/local.xml.sample
...
skin/frontend/base/
skin/frontend/default/
...
```

... and external Theme for it:

```
app/design/frontend/[theme name]/default/
errors/[theme name]/
errors/local.xml.[theme name]
skin/frontend/[theme name]/default/
README.[theme name]
```

But when I try to add theme`s repository as submodule to the root of project ...

```
$ git submodule add -b theme_name git://theme_repository.git .
'' already exists in the index
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the content of a submodule in the *current* directory (already versioned, hence "already existing in the index").
You would need to use:

```
git submodule add -b theme_name git://theme_repository.git aDirectory
```

`aDirectory` would be a *new* directory not existing yet, and created to be the root folder of your submodule.

You can then add symlinks to that new folder, in order for `app/design/frontend/[theme name]` or `skin/frontend/[theme name]` to renference the right folder.